# Apple account and regional issues

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My apple account is registered in Taiwan. If I want to poblish my application to other countries, such as mainland China, do I need to register for a Chinese account? Can I continue to use my Taiwanese developer account to publish my app to China?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can distribute App to store for any country, By default App distributed to all countries, if you need it for specific country then you have to select / deselect countries.

To edit country list log in on `https://appstoreconnect.apple.com`select your app, then got to **`Pricing and Availability`** section, where you can select country.

Comment: You know that China's servers are placed in mainland China, will there be additional restrictions on publishing applications in mainland China?

Comment: For apps some restriction by China not by Apple, you can found some detail on https://themindstudios.com/blog/how-to-launch-an-app-in-china/